# Repeat the macro and save under different file name each time

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below to automate a certain action and save the file. But I need to repeat the action and save it under a different file name each time. 3 times to be specific.

I am not sure what is the best way to do it. Please help

```
Sub Proof()
Dim i As Long, Di As Long, Bi As Long
Const Dfirstrow As Double = 222
Const Bfirstrow As Double = 222
Dim Dlastrow As Long, Blastrow As Long
Dim Dmyvalue As Double, Bmyvalue As Double
Range("A2").Value = "Date / Time: " & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy / hh:nn:ss")
Dlastrow = Range("BE" & Dfirstrow).End(xlDown).Row
For Di = Dfirstrow To Dlastrow
Dmyvalue = Range("BE" & Di).Value
If Dmyvalue < 100 Then Range("BE" & Di).Value = -9 + Rnd * -3
Next Di
Blastrow = Range("AD" & Bfirstrow).End(xlDown).Row
For Bi = Bfirstrow To Blastrow
Bmyvalue = Range("AD" & Bi).Value
If Bmyvalue < 100 Then Range("AD" & Bi).Value = 46 + Rnd * 3
Next Bi
Sheets.Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\sgfancyj\Desktop\Profile_Macros\NEW\A", FileFormat:=Excel.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just add a loop from 1 to 3. Or you could repeat the SaveAs line.

Comment: I want to run all of the above code before it saves each time. If I repeated the saveas line using loop it will only run the code once and save it 3 times, right?

Comment: Put it all in a loop then.

Answer (score 0):

ive added a loop and a change to the file name for each save, just customize the file name part and the code should be good to go, comment on my channel if you want to know anything else   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfAhmae4iqA

```
Sub Proof()



    Dim x as long
    Dim i As Long, Di As Long, Bi As Long



    For x = 1 to 3 ‘however many times you would want to run it 

    Const Dfirstrow As Double = 222
    Const Bfirstrow As Double = 222
    Dim Dlastrow As Long, Blastrow As Long
    Dim Dmyvalue As Double, Bmyvalue As Double
    Range("A2").Value = "Date / Time: " & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy / hh:nn:ss")
    Dlastrow = Range("BE" & Dfirstrow).End(xlDown).Row
    For Di = Dfirstrow To Dlastrow
    Dmyvalue = Range("BE" & Di).Value
    If Dmyvalue < 100 Then Range("BE" & Di).Value = -9 + Rnd * -3
    Next Di
    Blastrow = Range("AD" & Bfirstrow).End(xlDown).Row
    For Bi = Bfirstrow To Blastrow
    Bmyvalue = Range("AD" & Bi).Value
    If Bmyvalue < 100 Then Range("AD" & Bi).Value = 46 + Rnd * 3
    Next Bi
    Sheets.Select
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=St & " " & " " & Ex_Ref & " " & Ref & ‘the file will have say save as different names each time           
    EnFileFormat:=Excel.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

      Debug.Print x & ".file saved."    ‘this displays this message in immediate window 
      Next x




    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried chaning the filename part but it is not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Would the code work in excel 97-2003?

Comment: there is a possibility it could not work in an older version. do you have your internet controls turned on in vba references?

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful feedback, please elaborate.